# What is the name of the controller used in Apple Mac systems?

Tags: mac

There is a “controller” in the Apple Mac systems. When installing Mac OS X, it detects the controller and provides more features. What is the name of the controller?

Comment: yes. If we install a Windows OS on a Mac. It doesnt have more Trackpad features when comparing to installing a OSX on a mac.
When a OSX is installed, it checks for a 'controller' and identifies it as a original Mac. I want to know name of that controller or chip whatever.

Comment: This is the link of that article...
http://www.howtogeek.com/178031/why-is-it-still-so-difficult-to-install-os-x-on-pcs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a “controller” in the Apple Mac systems. […] What is the name
>   of the controller?

You probably are thinking of the [system management controller (SMC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller) but good luck trying to get around that. That is directly connected to driver requirements on Mac OS X as well as Mac OS X related hardware.